# Subtracting multiple cells on Google Sheets + the use of IF ELSE

Tags: google-sheets-formula

It's been weeks since I've been trying to solve this problem, I tried various formulas for this (ArrayFormula, ABS, SUMPRODUCT, using a negative sign on the cells), but I can't seem to get it right.

The correct way will always be manually subtracting the cells one by one but this will cause too much delay or problem if we have more than 100 rows on the sheets.

```
=if(D14<(E3-E4-E5-E6-E7-E8-E9-E10-E11-E12-E13),D14,E3-E4-E5-E6-E7-E8-E9-E10-E11-E12-E13)
```

Here's the link to the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAPQHKupKglBAJpoxrcVqWP343m0P5QOj8zp1FvasEA/edit?usp=sharing

The overall idea for this is that the Total Purchased should be compared to the total sold. The 2201 value on the total sold is retrieved from another transactions sheet and it just totals every sold item, and then starting from E4 (170 in cell value) onwards, it decreases since we just need to know the number of sold items from that certain row.

Thank you very much for taking the time to read this. I'm looking forward to getting help from this as this stresses me for weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cumulative function

```
=arrayformula(mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D)))
```

and include in your formula in E4 as follows

```
=arrayformula(if(D4:D<($E$3-(mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D)))),D4:D))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out! This was solved so fast! Have a great day!

Comment: Just another question, I'm having an issue with row #21, from the manual calculation, I get 260 as sold, and I just get false so I tried something out from your formula but I'm getting 162 instead of 260, do you know an easy work around for this? Thank you so much!

Comment: can you explain why 260?

Comment: When I sum the manual calculation (B4:B), it's balanced as 2370. But on the column with the formula E4:E21 it shows up as 2110. 

The 260 is from the manually calculated rows (B4:20) since it's still less than the overall total sold.

It reached to Row 23 because the overall is 2370 and after that row the next rows should be 0. Or is the calculation wrong? Sorry for the bother!

Comment: I'm leaving some few comments with what I did with the manual calculation that's why it's like that. I hope this helps. Let me know if it's still confusing please. I don't know how to properly explain it. Thanks so much!

Comment: @player0 - Hi, guys! Do you know the reason why it shows as false instead of 260 on row 21?https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAPQHKupKglBAJpoxrcVqWP343m0P5QOj8zp1FvasEA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Drmtry https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhDTb.png

Comment: I can find 260 by `=arrayformula(if(if(D4:D<($E$3-(mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D)))),D4:D,)="",D4:D,if(D4:D<($E$3-(mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D)))),D4:D,)))`

Comment: Hi, @MikeSteelson! Thank you for that! My only problem now is it continues to calculate after it reached 2370 (the last number should be 260 since it has not been sold yet). I'll research more into this. I didn't expect that multiple subtraction is difficult via google sheets.

Comment: I can't get a satisfied solution. However, if your main problem is to write `-B4-B5-B6-B7-B8-B9...` , you can work with a cumulative column with `=arrayformula((mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D))))` instead of `-B4-B5-B6-B7-B8-B9...`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Mike! I'll figure this out. This is already a big help!

Comment: @MikeSteelson If I want to calculate the overall total if I subtract B4 until last cell above, what formula should I use?

Comment: I tried `mmult(1*(transpose(row(D4:D))<=row(D4:D)),if(D4:D="",0,D4:D))` but it doesn't work.

I need to replace D4:D on this the else part of `if(D4:D="",0,D4:D)`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why not `=sum(D4:D)`